# Facebook App does not Autobookmark (as documentation promises)

Tags: facebook

The app (trophy manager), uses iframe, zynga games autobookmarks for example (without user requests), what am I missing? The documentation in facebook developers says it bookmarks on install and sorts the apps after activity, but it does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*zynga games autobookmarks for example (without user requests), what am I missing?*" What you're seeing is the partnership between Zynga and Facebook at work.  They've developed a great "I'll scratch your back if you scratch mine" relationship.  I'm sure it cost a lot of time and money and legal time and legal money for that agreement to be reached.   Facebook does have a team setup to handle just this sort of thing.  I would suggest having your business development team contact facebook to see what type of deal can be arranged.

"*The documentation in facebook developers says it bookmarks on install and sorts the apps after activity, but it does not seem to be the case.*"  Then log it as a bug with Facebook and put the bug report link here so others can see.